# sharepoint 2010 results.aspx look and feel

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

Am relatively new to Sharepoint 2010 so apologies if this is a lame question.

On a public facing website with a search function from Sharepoint 2010 a search query takes you to a page http://www.site.com/searchCenter/results.aspx?k=searchstring

That page has a blue header with orange, a left column with refinements and then the search results returned in a central column.

Is there a way to change the ENTIRE look of that page to fit the look of the public site and embed the results returned into the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will just need to modify the minimal.master which is the master page that the search site should be using. You should be able to make the search results page look exactly like the rest of your site if you want it to.

Comment: Additionally you might want to look into modifying the XSLT which returns the search results.